# create resource in terraform conditionally

Tags: terraform

I want to be able to create a resource depending on if a resource with the same name exists or not. count can be used to conditionally create the resource but how do I check for the existence of a resource by name in terraform?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Comment: Manually created resources where they are not present (via tf), asked this question wondering if there is a way to check before creating them...would data sources help in any way?

Comment: I explained in the answer you have to create your own data source for that. Tf has no functionality to check if there are any pre-existing resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ow do I check for the existence of a resource by name in terraform?

**You can't**, as there is no build in functionality in TF to check for pre-existing resources. But you can develop your own  [external data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source) to do that. Since its a **fully custom** data source, you can program it to check for the existence of your resources, and use that information later in your TF config files.

Comment: I was wondering if one could `try` on the existence of the resource exported attribute Map, but those errors are in the un-catchable category. I also think checking if that object is empty would throw an error. This could very well be the only plausible algorithm.

Comment: @MattSchuchard What do you mean by "if that object is empty"? Maybe you could expand on that in an answer?

Comment: Since neither of those options seem possible in the current DSL, that answer would not be as good as yours.